# Posterior distribution of ATE with Bayesian propensity score model?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, propensity-scores, weighted-regression

I am using propensity score weighting (PSW) to estimate the average treatment effect (ATE) of some treatment $D$ on an outcome $Y$ with covariates $X$. I have seen several ways in the literature (both analytic and bootstrap) for estimating the uncertainty of the PSW estimate.

I'd like to use a Bayesian multi-level model of the propensity score. I assume there is not an analytic formula for the uncertainty of the resulting PSW treatment effect estimate. I could use the bootstrap but the model is prohibitively expensive to fit (using Stan).

But since I'm using Stan I can get a big sample of the posterior distribution of the propensity scores. I could simply, for each posterior sample, calculate the PSW estimate (e.g. using the Horvitz-Thompson estimator). Now I have a distribution of ATE estimates. Does this distribution appropriately capture the uncertainty of my ATE estimate? Or do I need to incorporate the uncertainty of the ATE given the propensity score model? How can I do that? Any references would be great.

Here are two useful references I found but I don't think they address my question as the former is about propensity score regression and matching (not weighting) and the latter only mentions delta and bootstrap.

[1] Bayesian Propensity Score Estimators: Incorporating Uncertainties in Propensity Scores into Causal Inference by An

[2] Propensity Score Weighting with Multilevel Data by Li et al.

Comment: How could `I could use the bootstrap but the model is prohibitively expensive to fit (using Stan).` be done?

Comment: I was thinking I would bootstrap the whole thing: draw a bootstrap sample of (X,y), fit a propensity score model, calclate the Horvitz-Thompson estimate.